# How can I access my spring framework select value via JQuery

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp

I am trying to catch the current value of my `<sf:select>` with JQuery and got stucked and I don't know how to search this solution on Google.

**JSP code**

```
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label for="tipoUtilidade" class="control-label">
    Tipo <span class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Escolha o tipo de atendimento..."></span>
  </label>
  <sf:select path="modulo" class="form-control input-sm" onchange="mudaTipo()">
    <sf:option value="" label="Escolha o tipo..." />
    <sf:options items="${todosModulos}" itemValue="codigo" itemLabel="label"/>
  </sf:select>
</div>

<div id="bico_id" class="col-md-2">
  <label for="bico.id" class="control-label">Bico</label>   
  <sf:select path="bico.id" class="form-control input-sm">
    <sf:option value="">...</sf:option>
    <sf:options items="${todosBicosPosto}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="numeroModulo" />
  </sf:select>
</div>
```

I want to access this `path=modulo` with `itemValue=codigo` via JQuery to make a if statement to test if `${todosModulos}` is "Areia" or "Agua" (both Strings) to hide or show the div with `id="bico_id">` and I have no clue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This part of code

```
<sf:select path="modulo" class="form-control input-sm" onchange="mudaTipo()">
...
</sf:select>
```

will be translated to HTML code

```
<select id="modulo" name="modulo" ...>
...
</select>
```

So you can use ID selector and add on change function similar to this:

```
$("#modulo").on('change', function(){
  if($(this).val()==='Areia' || $(this).val()==='Agua')
    $('#bico_id').hide();
  else
    $('#bico_id').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to access this path=modulo with itemValue=codigo via JQuery

Try using:

```
$('select[name=modulo]')
```

> make a if statement to test if ${todosModulos} is "Areia" or "Agua"
>   (both Strings) to hide or show the div with id="bico_id"

```
//change to .val(), in-case you need `value` attribute
var modulo=$('select[name=modulo]').find('option:selected').text();
var bico_id=$('#bico_id').show();
if(/^Areia|Agua$/.test(modulo)){
    bico_id.hide();
}
```